# How to automatically capture respondent's email ID in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am sending a survey sheet to participants to their email ids. I am able to capture and see the responses to each question asked. However, I am not able to see the corresponding Respondent's email id.

Is there any way to auto capture the respondent's email address automatically in the response sheet?

Comment: Short hack, ask them in the form itself, I haven't created Google Forms, from quite some time, but seen people do it

Comment: If the underlying question is "how to *link* answer to participant", there is no workaround, as the participant privacy can't be compromised and they can also put any email address in the form.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Google Forms Pre-Filled Answers feature. This allows you to pre-fill a form value when you send it out to someone. This is described here:

Follow the steps here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en

You will get a form URL with an email query string parameter like this which you can then modify by changing the email address for each user:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/111122223333/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1731330325=me@example.com

Here are some high level steps to accomplish this:

> 1. Open a form in Google Forms
> 2. In the menu bar, click `Responses` > `Get pre-filled URL`
> 3. Click the email field and enter a test value
> 4. Click submit
> 5. Choose Get pre-filled link and identify the parameter name associated with the email address you entered
> 6. Create a program that does a "mail merge" with the URL adding the recipient's email address to the parameter in question for each recipient email

Answer (score 1):

Go to your form and click on **'Settings'** icon. There you will find a checkbox to collect email address of the respondent and save it. You can now see a column in the response sheet which contains email addresses.

[image]

Comment: chis checkbox only adds an email field to the form, it doesn't collect the logged in user's email

Comment: I'm not sure if you have tried doing it. But I verified it on my end. It doesn't add an email field to the form.  The respondent's email address is automatically captured and is present as a separate column in the responses sheet(Which is a google sheet that gets filled automatically when someone submits a form).

Comment: oh yes I did. It does what you describe only if you use Suite for business, or whatever it called, and your domain emails use gmail.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Got it. I did not try creating Google forms from my personal gmail account. I'm not sure how it works.